# Notice: Undefined index: when trying to submit form with a null array

Tags: php, undefined

Good day, could anybody be willing to explain this notice everytime I submit the form. This is my code below:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="f"> 
<TABLE id="dataTable" border="1">
<thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td>Model</td>
            <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</TABLE>
<br>

<input type="text" name="ProductNme" id="item" >
<input type="text" name="ProductNme" id="price" >
<input type="text" name="ProductNme" id="qty" >

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
```

```
<?php

if($_POST['submit']) {


    $dbC = new imsFunction();

    if ($_POST['item'] == null) {
        echo 'No Data';
    } else {
        foreach ($_POST['item'] as $key => $value) { 

            $item = $_POST["item"][$key];
            $price = $_POST["price"][$key];
            $qty = $_POST["qty"][$key];

                $sql = $dbC->qryExec('Insert Into tbl_test (item,price,quant) Values (?, ?, ?)', [$item, $price, $qty]);
                //$sql = mysql_query("insert into your_table_name values ('','$item', '$price', '$qty')");  
            }  
        } 
    }
}
```

?>

This is the javascript code to add the data to the table rows.

```
function addRow(tableID) {

    var enteredItem = $("#item").val();
    var enteredPrice = $("#price").val();
    var enteredQty= $("#qty").val();

    if (!enteredItem) {
        alert("Please entere item name!");
    } else {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name="chkbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = "<input type='text' name='item[]' value='"+enteredItem+"' readonly />";

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell3.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  name='price[]' value='"+enteredPrice+"' readonly />";

        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell4.innerHTML = "<input type='text'  name='qty[]' value='"+enteredQty+"' readonly />";

        document.getElementById('item').value='';
    }
}
```

The input was name like 'item[]'. what I want to do is to catch error if the user submit button without adding data first. But what happen is, it gives out a Notice that Undefined index: item in the foreach loop.

Comment: `if ($_POST['item'] == null){` will return false even though there is no item. Use `if (empty($_POST['item'])) {`

Answer (score 0):

When testing for incoming data, always assume the worst. In this case, the test `$_POST['item']==null` may fail if it hasn’t been set in the first place.

The safer approach is:

```
if(isset($_POST['item']) && is_array($_POST['item'])) {

}
```

The second part of the test is just in case.

By the way, if you do test specifically for a `null` value you should use `===` to distinguish it from other falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes on input fields name

```
<input type="text" name="ProductNme" id="item" >
<input type="text" name="ProductNme" id="price" >
<input type="text" name="ProductNme" id="qty" >
```

They are all named : `ProductNme` that's why these lines won't work

```
$item = $_POST["item"][$key];
        $price = $_POST["price"][$key];
        $qty = $_POST["qty"][$key];
```

These indexes(`item`,`price`,`qty`) do not exist in $_POST array sent to the server.
Hence the *undefined index* message.
Good luck